# Generating list of functions from list of expressions

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I know how to create a function from concrete expression like

```
Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2]
```

But what if I have a list of expressions list1 and I know the set of variables which can occur in this list. I want to map all expressions of list1 to curresponding functions from these variables. Like

```
{x^2 + y^2, z^2, x, y}
```

should be mapped to

```
{
  Function[{x,y,z}, x^2 + y^2], 
  Function[{x,y,z}, z^2], 
  Function[{x,y,z}, x], 
  Function[{x,y,z}, y]
}
```

I've tried

```
Function[{x,y,z}, #] &/@ list1
```

but this doesn't work. Can someone help me with solution?

Comment: Something like `g = Function[{x, y, z}, #] & /@ l1; g[[1]][a, b, c]`?

Comment: Or this way?`g = Function[{x, y, z}, #] &@l1; g[a, b, c][[1]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
exprs = {x^2 + y^2, z^2, x, y};
Replace[Function[{x, y, z}, body], {Rule[body, #]} & /@ exprs, {-1}]
```

> ```
> {
>    Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2], 
>    Function[{x, y, z}, z^2], 
>    Function[{x, y, z}, x], 
>    Function[{x, y, z}, y]
> }
> ```